# Adjacent CSS Selector (+) not working

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the "plus" CSS Selector which should target immediate siblings, but it's not working for some inexplicable reason. Either this is a bug or I don't understand how it's supposed to work.

The elements B, C and D should all be red – but they're still bisque.

```css
span {
 display: block;
 background-color: bisque;
}
.outside + .outside {
 background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">A</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">B</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">C</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">D</span>
</span>
```

I've also tried a few variations – i.e. `span.outside + span.outside`, 
`span.outside + *`, `.outside ~ .outside` – but none of them seem to work. The elements only become red if I delete the bisque declaration.

Comment: the color you see is of the inside span. You set span as display block so it takes the whole width

Comment: Add `.outside { padding: 10px; }` and you'll probably see what's happening. (Protip: *"Either this is a bug or I don't understand how it's supposed to work."* – it's almost without exception the latter.)

Comment: I see my mistake in the fiddle, but I still don't understand the problem in the actual project. I'll try to make a better fiddle (and hopefully find the solution myself). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `background-color: bisque` on `outside` not on `span`

```css
.outside {
  display: block;
  background-color: bisque;
}
.outside + .outside {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">A</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">B</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">C</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">D</span>
</span>
```

Or you can target `.inside` like this `.outside + .outside .inside`

```css
span {
  display: block;
  background-color: bisque;
}
.outside + .outside .inside {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">A</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">B</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">C</span>
</span>
<span class="outside">
 <span class="inside">D</span>
</span>
```